# Convert Categorical data for neural network

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use neural network on [Mushrooms data set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data). I know I have to convert it into numeric data or binary data in order to use it for neural network. Currently I have it in `data.frame` format. I know how to apply neural network just want help in converting it so I can input it in this formula.

```
library(neuralnet)
trainingdata=read.csv(file="agaricus-lepiota.data",header=FALSE, sep=",")
colnames(trainingdata)[1] <- "Output"
```

Here is the conversion part i need help with

```
neuralnet(Output~.,trainingdata, hidden=3, threshold=0.01)
```

Comment: is it your homework? what have you tried so far?

Comment: added the code i have done so far